# How can I create an array with key value pairs?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I add key value pairs to an array?

This won't work:

```
public function getCategorieenAsArray(){

    $catList = array();

    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT datasource_id, title FROM table";
    if ($rs=C_DB::fetchRecordset($query)) {
        while ($row=C_DB::fetchRow($rs)) {
            if(!empty($row["title"])){
                array_push($catList, $row["datasource_id"] ."=>". $row["title"] );
            }
        }
     }

    return($catList);
}
```

Because it gives me:

```
Array ( [0] => 1=>Categorie 1 [1] => 5=>Categorie 2 [2] => 2=>Caterorie 2 )
```

And I expect:

```
Array ( [1] =>Categorie 1 [5] => Categorie 2  )
```

Comment: Can someone with more rep edit this question and fix the line break?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Use the [square bracket syntax](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying):

```
if (!empty($row["title"])) {
    $catList[$row["datasource_id"]] = $row["title"];
}
```

`$row["datasource_id"]` is the key for where the value of `$row["title"]` is stored in.

Answer (score 156):

```
$data =array();
$data['user_code']  = 'JOY' ;
$data['user_name']  = 'JOY' ;
$data['user_email'] = 'joy@cargomar.org';
```

Comment: This simple answer explains it well for me.

Comment: The only thing with this solution is that this way you can only add key-value pairs to the end of the array, even if you have integer keys. PHP arrays are ordered, so if you want to prepend an array with a key-value pair, you have to do this: `$data = ['user_email' => joy@cargomar.org'] + $data`.

Answer (score 16):

My PHP is a little rusty, but I believe you're looking for indexed assignment. Simply use:

```
$catList[$row["datasource_id"]] = $row["title"];
```

In PHP arrays are actually maps, where the keys can be either integers or strings. Check out [PHP: Arrays - Manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the single value array key-value as

```
$new_row = array($row["datasource_id"]=>$row["title"]);
```

inside while loop, and then use `array_merge` function in loop to combine the each new `$new_row` array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function in your application to add keys to indexed array.

```
public static function convertIndexedArrayToAssociative($indexedArr, $keys)
{
    $resArr = array();
    foreach ($indexedArr as $item)
    {
        $tmpArr = array();
        foreach ($item as $key=>$value)
        {
            $tmpArr[$keys[$key]] = $value;
        }
        $resArr[] = $tmpArr;
    }
    return $resArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need array_push function.if you want to add multiple item it works fine. simply try this and it worked for me

```
class line_details {
   var $commission_one=array();
   foreach($_SESSION['commission'] as $key=>$data){
          $row=  explode('-', $key);
          $this->commission_one[$row['0']]= $row['1'];            
   }

}
```