# Using an array with a key as an array key

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, key

I am using arrays with keys as the key to an array, in the code like below,

```
        $team = array();
        $counter = 0;

        $sql = "SELECT Home, Away, Result, Points FROM schedule";
        $schedulequery = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        // divy out the points
        if (mysqli_num_rows($schedulequery) > 0) {
            while($teamrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($schedulequery)) {

                $points = $teamrow["Points"]; 
                if ($teamrow["Result"] == "Home"){
                    $team[$teamrow["Home"]] = $team[$teamrow["Home"]] + $points;
                }
                if ($teamrow["Result"] == "Tie"){
                    $team[$teamrow["Home"]] = $team[$teamrow["Home"]] + ($points/2);
                    $team[$teamrow["Away"]] = $team[$teamrow["Away"]] + ($points/2);
                }
                if ($teamrow["Result"] == "Away"){
                    $team[$teamrow["Away"]] = $team[$teamrow["Away"]] + $points;
                }
                if ($teamrow["Result"] == "HomeForfeit"){
                    $team[$teamrow["Home"]] = $team[$teamrow["Home"]] - $points;
                    $team[$teamrow["Away"]] = $team[$teamrow["Away"]] + $points;
                }
                if ($teamrow["Result"] == "AwayForfeit"){
                    $team[$teamrow["Home"]] = $team[$teamrow["Home"]] + $points;
                    $team[$teamrow["Away"]] = $team[$teamrow["Away"]] - ($points/2);
                }
                if ($teamrow["Result"] == "DuelForfeit"){
                    $team[$teamrow["Home"]] = $team[$teamrow["Home"]] - ($points/2);
                    $team[$teamrow["Away"]] = $team[$teamrow["Away"]] - ($points/2);
                }
            }
        }
```

This code is working and successfully updating in my MySql table (that part of the code not included) every time one of these lines is used I get a "PHP Notice:  Undefined index: " error.

Is this bad practice or is this the wrong syntax? I am confused why it is working but still tells me undefined index.

EDIT:
The lines that are erroring out are all the times I access a line with a double array like "$team[$teamrow["Home"]]". Any time one of those is accessed I get an error.

EDIT: I think I get it.. I am creating a new key in an array that doesn't already exist?

Comment: What line is erroring out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: I was creating a new index in an associative array that did not yet exist. error free code here:

$team = array();
            $counter = 0;

```
        $sql = "SELECT Home, Away, Result, Points FROM schedule";
        $schedulequery = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        // divy out the points
        if (mysqli_num_rows($schedulequery) > 0) {
            while($teamrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($schedulequery)) {

                $points = $teamrow["Points"]; 
                if ($teamrow["Result"] == "Home"){
                    if (!isset($team[$teamrow["Home"]])){
                        $team[$teamrow["Home"]] = 0;
                    }

                    $team[$teamrow["Home"]] = $team[$teamrow["Home"]] + $points;
                }
                if ($teamrow["Result"] == "Tie"){
                    if (!isset($team[$teamrow["Home"]])){
                        $team[$teamrow["Home"]] = 0;
                    }
                    if (!isset($team[$teamrow["Away"]])){
                        $team[$teamrow["Away"]] = 0;
                    }
                    $team[$teamrow["Home"]] = $team[$teamrow["Home"]] + ($points/2);
                    $team[$teamrow["Away"]] = $team[$teamrow["Away"]] + ($points/2);
                }
                if ($teamrow["Result"] == "Away"){
                    if (!isset($team[$teamrow["Away"]])){
                        $team[$teamrow["Away"]] = 0;
                    }
                    $team[$teamrow["Away"]] = $team[$teamrow["Away"]] + $points;
                }
                if ($teamrow["Result"] == "HomeForfeit"){
                    if (!isset($team[$teamrow["Home"]])){
                        $team[$teamrow["Home"]] = 0;
                    }
                    if (!isset($team[$teamrow["Away"]])){
                        $team[$teamrow["Away"]] = 0;
                    }

                    $team[$teamrow["Home"]] = $team[$teamrow["Home"]] - $points;
                    $team[$teamrow["Away"]] = $team[$teamrow["Away"]] + $points;
                }
                if ($teamrow["Result"] == "AwayForfeit"){
                    if (!isset($team[$teamrow["Home"]])){
                        $team[$teamrow["Home"]] = 0;
                    }
                    if (!isset($team[$teamrow["Away"]])){
                        $team[$teamrow["Away"]] = 0;
                    }

                    $team[$teamrow["Home"]] = $team[$teamrow["Home"]] + $points;
                    $team[$teamrow["Away"]] = $team[$teamrow["Away"]] - ($points/2);
                }
                if ($teamrow["Result"] == "DuelForfeit"){
                    if (!isset($team[$teamrow["Home"]])){
                        $team[$teamrow["Home"]] = 0;
                    }
                    if (!isset($team[$teamrow["Away"]])){
                        $team[$teamrow["Away"]] = 0;
                    }

                    $team[$teamrow["Home"]] = $team[$teamrow["Home"]] - ($points/2);
                    $team[$teamrow["Away"]] = $team[$teamrow["Away"]] - ($points/2);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: dam, you figured it out just as i was typing up the code

Answer (score 0):

from what i can tell the problem might be the lines like `$team[$teamrow["Home"]] = $team[$teamrow["Home"]] + $points;`.

at the start of your code you initialize `$team` as an empty array with no indexes or values. then in your while loop you have lines like `$team[$teamrow["Home"]] = $team[$teamrow["Home"]] + $points;` and the problem is the right side of the `=`. what is the value of `$team[$teamrow["Home"]]` is being added to `$points` in the very first iteration (when $team is uspposed to be an empty array)?

since it appears you are using integers, at the start of your while loop i would do the following

```
if(!isset($team[$teamrow["Home"]]))
{
    $team[$teamrow["Home"]] = 0;
}
```

and likewise i'd do the same with `$team[$teamrow["Away"]]`. this way if `$team[$teamrow["Home"]]` is undefined it'll be given a value of 0

Comment: Thanks Memor-X, I didn't realize you couldn't do that at first; I guess the computer is able to infer what I meant, but still says that it doesnt like it. You are able to declare new indexes freely if you are using numerical keys though, correct?

Comment: @ben sort of, it's not the computer inferring the empty variable but PHP (other languages on a computer will throw an error and crash when you try to do that) and yes, as you can see from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1138382/1028804) it'll work with integer keys too. as for why it's still not liking it maybe also using [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) (ie. `!array_key_exists([$teamrow["Home"],$team)`) though i would have thought `isset` would have been enough