# Adding key in an Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Im studying in array, and I was wondering How can I add key to this kind of array?

```
{  
   "items":[  
      {  
         "count":"1",
         "id":123,
         "description":"Bag",
         "price":11

      },
      {  
         "count":1,
         "id":1234,
         "description":"10% Discount",
         "price":-1.1

      }
   ],
   "total":9.9,
   "discount_total":9.9
}
```

because I needed convert the array to have a key base on the id inside the array.

```
{  
   "items":{  
      "123":{  
         "count":"1",
         "cart_id":123,
         "description":"Bag",
         "price":11
      },
      "1234":{  
         "count":1,
         "cart_id":1234,
         "description":"10% Discount",
         "price":-1.1
      }
   },
   "total":9.9,
   "discount_total":9.9
}
```

and this is my code

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$cart_array = json_decode('{  
   "items":[  
      {  
         "count":"1",
         "cart_id":123,
         "plu":"TP16",
         "description":"Bag"

      },
      {  
         "count":1,
         "cart_id":1234,
         "plu":"DISCT10",
         "description":"10% Discount"

      }
   ],
   "total":9.9,
   "discount_total":9.9
}');

foreach ($cart_array->items as $item)
{
    $construct["cart_id"] = $item->cart_id;
}
```

I wanted to ask how can I put the id in the array? I cant use `$cart_array['id'] =  $value`, it returns error.

> **Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array**

I could really use some explanation here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I add key value pairs to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138359/how-can-i-add-key-value-pairs-to-an-array)

Comment: @piyush Yes, I look through it and tried to understand it and looks like this is what im looking for. and another thing im missing is making the json_decode true. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to loop at all. You can use array_column to make an array associative with one line of code.

```
$cart_array['items'] = array_column($cart_array['items'], NULL, 'cart_id');
```

https://3v4l.org/cPD5n

Comment: I changed the correct answer since this also answer my another problem in deconstructing my array (removing the key after some validation) thanks

Answer (score 2):

Following code can help you.

```
<?php
$json = '{  
   "items":[  
      {  
         "count":"1",
         "cart_id":123,
         "plu":"TP16",
         "description":"Small Four Seasons"

      },
      {  
         "count":1,
         "cart_id":1234,
         "plu":"DISCT10",
         "description":"10% Discount"

      }
   ],
   "total":9.9,
   "discount_total":9.9
}';
$data = json_decode($json,TRUE); //json decode 
foreach ($data['items'] as $key => $value) 
{
    $data['items'][$value['cart_id']] = $value;
    unset($data['items'][$key]);
} 
echo "<pre>";print_r($data);die;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your application to add keys to indexed array.

```
foreach($obj as $key=>$val){
  foreach ($val as $index=>$content){
    $data[$content['id']]=$content;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get same output json data as per you want :

```
$array = json_decode($data,true);
if(isset($array['items']) && count($array['items']) > 0){
    foreach($array['items'] as $key => $value){
        $value['cart_id'] = $value['id'];
         unset($value['id']);
        $array['items'][$value['cart_id']] = $value;
        unset($array['items'][$key]);

                   }
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($array);
echo json_encode($array);
```